# How did Admiral Janeway actually travel back in time?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-voyager

How did she actually manage to travel back in time and actually end up in the delta quadrant from the alpha quadrant instantly using the chrono deflector?

Comment: Note that most (not quite all) controlled forms of time travel in ST also allowed you to travel to any point in space, IIRC.  Even the uncontrolled ones seemed to send you through space as well as time roughly as often as not.  The only exceptions that spring to mind are Spock's sun-slingshot maneuver (obviously tied to the sun in question) and the Borg's time travel device in First Contact (which had to be limited for plot reasons).  So Janeway's device isn't unusual in this respect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say, she used a **[chrono deflector](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chrono_deflector)**, which works by using a **tachyon pulse** to form a directable temporal rift.

> The device operated by generating a powerful tachyon pulse to form a [temporal rift](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Temporal_rift), which could then be directed to a specific time and place. Although able to generate a stable rift, the device also produced a large amount of [tachyokinetic energy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tachyokinetic_energy) as a byproduct of its operation, posing the risk that it would burn itself out after a single use, prohibiting a return trip for the user.

[Tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) are particles that travel faster than the speed of light. If such particles really do exist, it's possible they could indeed be used to facilitate time travel:

> If such particles did exist, they could be used to build a [tachyonic antitelephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone) and send signals faster than light, which (according to special relativity) would lead to violations of [causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_(physics)).

Here's the temporal rift:

[image]

Comment: Yeah but the rift was already there in the delta quadrant before admiral janeway had even fired the chrono deflector

Comment: @Darren - It's a time-machine. One end comes out in the future.

Comment: @Richard yeah good point haha

Comment: Definitely proud of you for this answer, @randal'thor!  :-)